# Filter the Node Locations view in the navigation menu

Tags: views, google-maps

I'm using Gmap Views to show where each Eastern Star Chapter in Maine is, both extant and historical. The automatic Node Locations map in the Navigation menu is displaying them correctly so far. What I would like to do is filter this so only nodes of type "chapter" are displayed, and preferably only ones marked as "active", although I won't generally have an exact geocode for the inactive ones. Thanks!

(This is very similar to a question I asked before, but it didn't get much input, so I'm asking it a different way this time.)

Answer (score 0):

Set up a taxonomy vocabulary (eg Status) with the terms 'active' 'closed' etc, and attach a term reference to the node.

Then filter your view on the term. Have a look at [Filter map to show single taxonomy or single content type](http://drupal.org/node/318215).